# Jsoup not getting html correctly(?)

Tags: java, android, html, listview

Ok so Im using Jsoup to download some html from a website and am trying to put said html in a listview. The app compiles with no errors but when i click the button the listview is empty. This (imo) could be due to the fact that i have not implemented the jsoup code correctly and its not downloading the html or because even though it is download the html correctly its not being added to the listview correctly (yes, i have implemented the internet permission). Here is my code:

```
package davidgb.baseballspain;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but);
    but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new doit().execute();
        }
    });}

public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
ListView lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lista);
    String result1;
    String result2;
    String result3;
    String result4;
    String result5;
    String result6;

    String[] resultsizq = {result1, result3, result5,};
    String[] resultsder = {result2, result4, result6,};

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
       CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
       lista.setAdapter(customAdapter);
   }

    Class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
       @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultsizq.length;
        }
        @Override
       public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customlayout,null);

            TextView resultsiz= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.resultsiz);
            TextView resultsde= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.resultsde);


            resultsiz.setText(resultsizq[position]);
            resultsde.setText(resultsder[position]);

           return view;
        }
    }



    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.rfebs.es/estadisticas/2017/liga/B_res.php").get();


            Elements result = doc.getElementsByClass("bianco_me");

            if (result.size() > 0) {

                result1 = result.get(1).text();

                result2 = result.get(2).text();

                result3 = result.get(3).text();

                result4 = result.get(4).text();

                result5 = result.get(5).text();

                result6 = result.get(6).text();

            }



        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}}
```

Comment: In `doit` class you declared `String result1` till `String result6` and then immediately stored its *current* value (which is default value - so `null`) in `String[] resultsizq = {result1, result3, result5,};`. This means that array is filled with `null`s. Even if you later update value of `result1` array still will hold its previous value.

Comment: I've been searching on google how to update the String[] after having downloaded the html but have found nothing. How would you do it sir?

Comment: Ok nevermind, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

**I retrieves the website logo using below Java code**

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
// Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
// Using Elements to get the class data
                Elements img = document.select("div[class=header-logo] a[title=AndroidBegin] img[src]");
// Locate the src attribute
                String imgSrc = img.attr("src");
// Download image from URL
                InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
// Decode Bitmap
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

**and Website Source Code is**

```
<div class="header-logo"><a href="http://www.androidbegin.com/" rel="home" title="AndroidBegin"><img src="http://www.androidbegin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Web-Logo.png" alt="AndroidBegin" class="header-logo" /></a></div>         
    </div><!-- $header_logo_align -->
```